# Order by repeated times LINQ ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have this `Report` model:

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReporterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReporterId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Reporter { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public ReportType ReportType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to return a `List<Report>` ordered by the most repeated element based on `ProductId` to the least repeated element.

Is there any way on how to do this with linq?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results You'll need to group your list by ProductId, then order by the count desc

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newList = List.GroupBy(p=> p.ProductId )
              .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Count())
              .SelectMany(x=> x).ToList();
```